# Sql Exception - Trying to attach a database file, but using the wrong path?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I've got an MVC project for an interview that was using a mock database. I'm trying to get it to to use an actual database connection now and use Entity Framework.

To do this, I've added a database file to my solution, and have a class that derives from DbContext. My problem is that when my app tries to access the Db context, I'm getting this error: 
[image]

Some context for this: I have the following projects in my solution:

```
Data <- The actual location of the .mdf file
Logic
Services
Tests
Web <- My MVC project
```

Based on the error, it looks like it's trying to access the mdf file from within the `App_Data` folder of the `Web` project instead of the `Data` project, but I don't know where I tell my solution the actual location of the database file .

My database file does seem to be set up correctly and working overall, though. I'm able to do migrations and update the db via Entity Framework. It's just at runtime, I get that error when my Service object tries to access it

[image]

Comment: Can you provide snippets to `Service` object and current data context (especially related with connection string and its naming, because your problem sounds like originated from wrong database connection)? Are you previously moved corresponding MDF file from `App_Data` to `Data` folder?

Comment: @andrio, Share your connection string! Problem is in connection string!